# I am customizing chat bot based on ALICE, need little help on changing name

Tags: python-2.7, aiml

see this site freetohack.com -> chatbot

It was developed using ALICE BOT as a base with some custom AIML.

The problem is when i ask -> what is your name, it replies am nameless

when i look at the corresponding code on AIML it mentioned  but when i change that name paramater example  save the file

and re ask what is your name, it replies I am.

I would like to mention the custom name, is there any possibility?

Comment: Please provide the details of what you have done til now.

Comment: I see nothing in this question indicating it has to do with JavaScript, jQuery, or HTML5. If you have code in those languages/libraries you'd like to share, you can keep the tags. Otherwise [edit] your question to remove tags which are not relevant. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: see this site freetohack.com -> chatbot

It was developed using ALICE BOT as a base with some custom AIML.

The problem is when i ask -> what is your name, it replies am nameless

when i look at the corresponding code on AIML it mentioned but when i change that name paramater example save the file

and re ask what is your name, it replies I am.

I would like to mention the custom name, is there any possibility?